# Adding individual titles from a vector to each R plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

For a function, I need to keep variable names in a vector and I use a function to plot density graphs of my variables.

My problem is as follows in summary ;

```
var_names <- c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb")

plotter <- function(x){
  
  plot(density(x),
       main = "",
       xlab = "",
       ylab = "")
  title(var_names)
  
  
}

par(mfrow=c(4,3),mar=c(1,1,1,1))

apply(mtcars,2,plotter)
```

[image]

Couldn't imagine how I can match them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var_names <- c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb")

plotter <- function(x, var){
  
  plot(density(x[[var]]),
       main = var,
       xlab = "",
       ylab = "")
}

par(mfrow=c(4,3),mar=c(2.1,2.1,2.1,1))

for(vn in var_names) plotter(mtcars, vn)
```

will yield
[image]

`for` loops are discouraged as they are slow. However in conjunction with plotting, which is slow in its own way or if the loop is only run for 11 times as in this example, `for` loops are perfectly fine and beginner friendly.

If you really need an apply-family function of plotters to have only one argument, the following will do:

```
var_names <- c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb")

plotter <- function(x){
  plot(density(x[[1]]),
     main = names(x),
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "")
}

par(mfrow=c(4,3),mar=c(2.1,2.1,2.1,1))

sapply(1:11,function(n) plotter(mtcars[n]))
```

Comment: thank god, thought that your first answer was what I looked for but the addition is exactly what I want to do. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach with `ggplot2` and the vector of names you have. You can format your data to longer and then filter the desired variables. Using facets and `geom_density()` you can avoid issues with titles. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Vector
var_names <- c("mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat","wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb")
#Data
mtcars %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  filter(name %in% var_names) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value))+
  geom_density()+
  facet_wrap(.~name,scales = 'free')+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am a big fan of `ggplot2` myself. Looking at the x axis values of `am`, `disp` and `vs` in your example this seems to be one of very rare occasions (I don't remember the last time) where base plot made the better design decision then ggplot.